# jQuery switvching DIVS with fade effect

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a very simple script to switch out divs. I would like to add in a fading transition to the script so that it is a bit smoother. However I cannot see what I am doing wrong (totally JS incompetent)
Thanks for any advice.

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {

$('#div2, #div3').hide();

$('.show').click(function () {

    $('.targetDiv').hide().fadeOut(1000);

    $('#div' + $(this).attr('target')).show();

});

});
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this in JSFiddle? That way we can tweak with the code and help you resolve the issue

Comment: `$('.targetDiv').fadeOut(1000);

    $('#div' + $(this).attr('target')).fadeIn(1000);`

Comment: As I was making the JSfiddle Connexo solved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies in this line: `$('.targetDiv').hide().fadeOut(1000);`
What is does - it sets style `display: none;` to all your elements you plan to cross-fade.

Also use the right attributes: `data-target="#div1"` instead of `target="#div1"` (which is not used for that purpose)

**Instead:**

```js
jQuery(function($) { // DOM ready

  // get all your targetDiv elements
  var $fadeDivs = $(".targetDiv");

  // Hide all but this one
  $fadeDivs.not("#div1").hide();

  $('.show').click(function(evt) {

    // prevent the browser doing default stuff
    evt.preventDefault();

    // get the target element - using data-target attribute!
    var selector = $(this).data('target');
    var $target = $( selector );

    // crossfade (don't forget to use .stop())
    $fadeDivs.not($target).stop().fadeOut(1000);
    $target.stop().fadeIn(1000);

  });

});
```

```css
.targets{ position:relative; height:100px; }
.targetDiv { position:absolute; height:100px; top:0; left:0;}
```

```html
<div class="targets">
  <div id="div1" class="targetDiv"><img src="//placehold.it/100x100/0bf"></div>
  <div id="div2" class="targetDiv"><img src="//placehold.it/100x100/f0b"></div>
  <div id="div3" class="targetDiv"><img src="//placehold.it/100x100/bf0"></div>
</div>

<a data-target="#div1" class="show">SHOW1</a>
<a data-target="#div2" class="show">SHOW2</a>
<a data-target="#div3" class="show">SHOW3</a>


<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```